# Block magento website by users country?

Tags: magento

i need to block the magento website by the visitors country without any extension , how to do it, where i need to edit the code? can i use .htaccess to do this?, else any native supports form the magento ?

please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try Maxmind's mod_geoip apache module:

http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2

If you are using WHM/cPanel then it is easy to block entire contry IP ranges from firewall like CSF. For more details how to block entire country in CSF visit following URL:

http://www.vpsdiscussions.com/index.php/topic,87.0.html

I think this one is more accurate:

http://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx

This one is magento free module:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-ip-security.html

Comment: Hi, it is working like charm thanks you so much, it is what i want

Comment: Which method did you try? Upvote. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx this method Sorry i can't Upvote because my reputation is low, but your answers is great  to appreciate

Comment: Here is another advance GEO IP block extension 
http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-geo-ip-ultimate-lock.html

Answer (score 1):

I already explained my experience here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewth/viewthread/469503/

I just think you shouldn't block the whole site, just the prices. You couldn't believe how many people outside the US find us & we can point them to our european or asian partners.

Hope it helps